# python annotations inside classes

Tags: python, function, class, annotations

I am tinkering with some graph algorithms and i want to make myself a general graph/edge framework.
I started by creating a Edge class as such:

```
class Edge:
    source = None
    destination = None
    isDirected = False
    isWeighted = False
    weight = None

    def __init__(self, source, destination, isDirected = False, weight = None):
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        self.isDirected = isDirected
        if not weight is None:
            self.isWeighted = True
            self.weight = weight

    def isSameEdge(self, edge: {'help': 'Some helpfull text goes here', 'type': Edge}):
    if \
        self.isDirected != edge.isDirected or \
        self.isWeighted != self.isWeighted or \
        self.weight != edge.weight:
        return False
    if self.isDirected:
        if \
            self.destination != edge.destination or \
            self.source != edge.source:
            return False
    return True
```

I get this error message:

```
def isSameEdge(self, edge: {'help': 'Some helpfull text goes here', 'type': Edge}):
NameError: name 'Edge' is not defined
```

My question is:

1) How can i inform python that edge parameter in isSameEdge function is of type Edge ?

2) I don't want to necessarily restrict the type.i just want Pycharm/any other IDE to drop me hints on the methods/class variables that are available to

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: did you manage to try out the provided solution? If it worked, please accept the answer, provide more feedback or post your own answer to close the solution. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Quoting **python.org**:

> Some tools may want to support type annotations in code that must be
>   compatible with Python 2.7. For this purpose this PEP has a suggested
>   (but not mandatory) extension where function annotations are placed in
>   a # type: comment. Such a comment must be placed immediately following
>   the function header (before the docstring).

You can check this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) for more information.

Python 3 code:

```
def embezzle(self, account: str, funds: int = 1000000, *fake_receipts: str) -> None:
    """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
    <code goes here>
```

is equivalent to the [python 2.7] following:

```
def embezzle(self, account, funds=1000000, *fake_receipts):
    # type: (str, int, *str) -> None
    """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
    <code goes here>
```

**Edit: To define variable argument data type**

You should define it as `Union[int, float, None]`

Comment: Are there wildcards in annotations ?

In Edge __init__ weight could be (None, Int, Float)

Comment: What is your python version? Is it > 3.5?